# Jquery defining a $(this) variable for reuse in many functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I have about 10 functions in a javascript file. Each function at the beginning has the following statement:

```
var $me = $(this);
```

Would it be better to define `$me` in the global scope and then redefine it at the beginning of each function? Or does it not make any difference? for example...

```
var $me;
function doo() {$me = $(this)}
function foo() {$me = $(this)}
// etc. etc.
```

Comment: No, it would not be better. There is no reason why `$me` should be "shared" between the functions, each has its own `$me` so it makes sense to be local. Besides, longer scope chains make variable lookup slower (theoretically).

Comment: I'd vote against the global scope. For readability and in case you plan to split your functions into modules later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NEVER implement your second option with `$me` defined globally, but overwritten in each local function.  That is a recipe for disaster.  If one function calls another (or triggers an event handler), `$me` will get overwritten and will get trounced from the proper value in the first function.  No - DO NOT DO THIS.

The correct way is to define a NEW local variable in each function that you use it in.  This is both faster and NOT prone to overwrite errors.  FYI, local variables are faster to access than global variables.

If you need a saved copy of $(this) in a function, then put:

```
var $me = $(this);
```

near the top of the function (inside the function body) so it's a temporary local variable.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I can think of between keeping the variable local and making it global are that you pollute the global space.

If you prefer it global for whatever reason, I would suggest doing

```
(function() {
    var $me;
    function doo() { $me = $(this); }
})();
```

instead, to keep the scope of `$me` from being truly global.

One important consideration, though, is that if you have only one `$me` declared, and you call another function which also sets `$me`, then you'll run into trouble.

Finally, it **makes more sense** for `$me` to be local, since it applies only to the function that it's in. Who is `$me` outside of a function call?

Comment: I'd still vote to not do it at all. `var $me = $(this)` is plenty straight forward, and there's no need for it to be global or the question would be moot.

Answer (score 0):

If these are global functions, there's probably no need for a "me" variable at all. This construct is typically used in an object's member functions. It's useful when you define a function that will be called by someone else, but that function needs a reference to your original object. For example, here we define an anonymous function that will be called by setTimeout:

```
{
   foo: function() {
     var me = this;
     setTimeout(function() {
       me.bar();
     }, 1000);
   },
   bar: function() {
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks more like the functions are used as event handlers or other jQuery-method callbacks, where `this` refers to a DOM element. It makes sense to avoid calling `$(this)` over and over again.